# ¿Cómo puedo colocar un RecyclerView o un ListView en un Fragment en Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragment, android-sqlite, recyclerview

quisiera saber cómo puedo colocar un `RecyclerView` en un `Fragment`  ya que de la forma en que se hace con una `Activity` la app me crashea, además estoy utilizando en mi `RecyclerView` una base de datos en `SQLite`, además este fragment lo estoy poniedo llamando con un botón de el menú de lista navigation drawer de mi activity_main

Comment: El código y el error que se muestra en el LogCat ?

Answer (score 1):

Crear un `RecyclerView` en un `Fragment` es muy similar a cuando lo creas en un `Activity`, sólo que tienes que cambiar el lugar donde defines el `RecyclerView` y donde le das los valores. A continuación te pongo un ejemplo de un trozo de código donde dentro de un `Fragment` meto un `RecyclerView`

El Xml del fragment :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listadoElem" 
        android:scrollbars="vertical">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

y el código es el siguiente:

```
public class NoticiasFragment  extends Fragment {
     protected static final String TAG = NoticiasFragment.class.getSimpleName();
     private RecyclerView recyclerView;

     public static NoticiasFragment newInstance(int position) {
        NoticiasFragment fragment = new NoticiasFragment ();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(Constants.ARG_POSITION, position);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_listado, container, false);

         recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listadoElem);           

         return rootView;
     }

     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     }

     @Override
     public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


          final LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
          recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

          //se crea el adapter de los elementos y se añade al RecyclerView
          //....
          recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

P.D.: He obviado la parte de la creación del adapter porque es similar a la del Activity y he supuesto que no tendrías problema con ello y así la respuesta quedaba un poco más clara. Espero te sirva de ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Que tal !

Estoy empezando a usar Android y de igual manera al principio me costó esta parte, y aunque **no estoy usando SQL, si no Firebase,** creo que es importante primero que sepas crear la lista (que te aparezca y luego implementar el SQL.

A continuación te explicaré cómo he implementado mi Recycler en mi Fragmento.

Primero que nada necesitarás:
   1) Lista de tu objeto, por ejemplo ---> List result ;
   2)Adaptador de tu objeto, por ejemplo --> ObjetoAdaptador adapter;
   3) y tu Recycler --> RecyclerView recyclerView;

Yo lo he implementado de la siguiente manera:

```
      public class ListFragment extends Fragment{
      private List<Objeto> result ;
      private ObjetoAdaptador adapter;
      private RecyclerView recyclerView;

       public ListClientFragment() {
        }

       public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       View rootView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);

       result = new ArrayList<>();

       recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_client);
       recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
       LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
       llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
       recyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);

       adapter = new ObjetoAdaptador(result,result.size(), getContext(), (Aqui podrías enviar tu Obj de SQL);  //<------------ LINEA IMPORTANTE

       recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
       return rootView;
  }
```

Se utiliza el adapter :
adapter = new ObjetoAdaptador(result,result.size(), getContext(), (Aqui podrías enviar tu Obj de SQL);

para formar la lista y dentro del Adaptador es donde  llamas a el objeto X de la lista y vas formando tu recuadro con los datos de éste.

A Continuación un ejemplo de un adaptador básico (creamos una clase, en este ejemplo  llamada: "ObjetoAdapter")

El uso del adaptador es importante e incluso puedes declarar OnClickListener dnetro de éste.
//**************************

```
       public class ObjetoAdapter extends 
       RecyclerView.Adapter<ObjetoAdapter.ObjetoViewHolder> {
       private List<Objeto> list;
       int position;
       Context context;

     @Override
    public ObjetoViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
      return new 


   ObjetoViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
  .inflate(R.layout.fragment_row, parent, false));

    }

  @Override
  public void onBindViewHolder(final ObjetoViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Objeto objeto = list.get(position);  
      holder.NombreObjeto.setText(objeto.getNombre(());

}

  //Aqui es donde el adaptador llega inicialmente, toma los datos y los 
  prepara para que los utilices con el ** holder **
  public ObjetoAdapter(List<Objeto> list, int position, Context context /**,Aqui puedes agregar tu SQL Objetc**/){ 
      this.list = list;
      this.position = position ;
      this.context = context;
     //This.SQL = SQL (por ejemplo) **** LA verdad no sé como se decla
  }


  @Override
  public int getItemCount() {
     return  list.size();
  }
  class ObjetoViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
      TextView NombreDeMiObjeto;


    //Aqui es donde buscas el ID de tu XML
      public ObjetoViewHolder(View itemView) {
      super(itemView);
      rvNombreObjeto = itemView.findViewById(R.id.nombre_objeto);


      }
   }


  }
```

Y Listo Solo necesitzs tener en Orden Tu XML (Que serían dos, uno en donde tengas tu Recycler y otro donde llames a tu Fila (Row) :

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recycler_view_barber"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="56dp"
                    android:overScrollMode="never"
                    app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
                    tools:context="alextrujillo4.com.barbershopadministrador.Fragment.Lista.ListaFragment"
                    tools:listitem="@layout/fragment_init_row"/>   
                   <!-- En este Ultimo(tools:listitem="" pones el nombre 
                   de tu XML ROW(Fila), esto es impoetante ya que 
                   de esta forma el Recycler sabe que dentro de él se encontrará
                   otro XML, en este caso varios más... --->

   </LinearLayout>
```

Y por ultimo u XML ROW llamado "fragment_row.xml", que en este ejmplo solo lo hemos construido para mostrar el NombredelObjeto.

```
  <LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:paddingRight="16dp"
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem"
android:orientation="vertical">
     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/nombre_objeto"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:textStyle="bold"/>
      </LinearLayout>
```

Y básicamente de esta forma construyes tu lista, no estoy muy familiarizado con el SQL pero si con la ayuda de esos datos construyes tu lista, deberas hacerlo llegar al Adaptador en donde, dependiendo de la ubicacion de la lista obbtendrás el objeto y con esos datos emperarás a construir tu Fila.

Espero que esto te aya sido de ayuda y haberme explicado bien, igual estoy empezando en esto de Android

Para mas información podrías buscar en la pagina de Android developers:
  https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html?hl=es-419

ojo no olvides agregar a tu Gradle:

```
  dependencies {
     compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+'
  }
```

Saludos !

Comment: gracias amigo, agradezco tu respuesta, implementare lo anterior y luego te comento como me fue con el sqlite, bracias bro

Comment: perfecto @PaulinoAcuña, quedo al pendiente

Comment: @PaulinoAcuña Que tal? te sirvió el post?