# ¿Como actualizar items de RecyclerView cuando se elimina un registro, actualiza o agrega?

Tags: android, recyclerview

Estoy trabajando con el patrón maestro detalle, cuando estoy en modo landscape se muestra la lista y el detalle (cabe recalcar que en el detalle podría llamar a un fragment que contenga la lógica para añadir un nuevo registro), es ahí donde va el problema cuando se elimina un registro en el modo landscape, muestra el mensaje de eliminado pero no actualiza los items de recyclerview, al igual cuando estoy en un smartphone para ver el detalle abro otra activity que contiene el detalle donde tengo la opción de eliminar el registro pero cuando retorno el registro aun figura en la lista.

> Ademas como obtener la posición del item eliminado desde la activity

Esta es la función que se encuentra en el adaptador.

```
void deleteItem(int index) {
        mDataset.remove(index);
        notifyItemRemoved(index);
    }
```

en el evento clic del boton eliminar que se encuentra en la activity

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.bt_eliminar:
                if(mFragment != null){
                    //Como obtener la posicion del recyclerview - este número es solo de ejemplo
                    mFragment.eliminar(1);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

> Como puedo obtener la posición para la función eliminar, desde la activity.

Quisiera que me brinden una explicación de como lograr este objetivo.

Este es mi primera pregunta acerca de este problema [actualizar items de recyclerview](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/96479/como-actualizar-los-items-de-un-recyclerview-en-el-patr%C3%B3n-master-detail-cuando), les dejo el código que he logrado con la ayuda de [David](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/50673/david) un gran desarrollador.

Código alojado en [Gist GitHub](https://gist.github.com/01luisrene/b3cf18f78d7f3eb4b7c7798edca72019)

Answer (score 2):

Los recyclerViews se comportan de manera diferente a las listas y por ende no deberian compararse, de hecho son bastante diferente en funcionamiento. Primero que nada, no te recomiendo usar el metodo, notifyDataSetChanged. En la misma documentacion de android habland acerca de los problemas de usarlo, debido a que los indices en los recycler view son dinamicos, es decir, ellos varian segun la informacion que se despliega en pantalla. La solucion correcta es un poco mas complicada que solo obtener el indice del elemento borrado. Lo que yo haria es lo siguiente.

1. Partiendo del hecho que tienes dos partes, una es tu recyclerView (que puede ser o no un fragment) y la segunda es tu vista detalle donde se aloja el boton de eliminar. Debes tener en alguna parte un arreglo, una lista algo como

> ```
> List<Object> data.
> ```

1. Cuando inflas la lista detalle, debes tener un metodo OnItemClick, en el recicler, envia esa posicion a la vista detalle, y cuando le des al boton eliminar, envia esa posicion por medio de una interfaz al acitivity que lo implementa, despues elimina del arreglo data el objecto en la posicion seleccionada.
2. Cuando lo hagas, crea un nuevo adapter del recyclerView, con data ya sin el objeto removido y vuelve a usar el metodo setAdapter(data) para que cargue de nuevo la info con un elemento menos.

Es un poco largo, pero es el precio a pagar por el rendimiendo que da el recyclerView. Mucha suerte

Answer (score 0):

Estoy trabajando Con reclyclers bueno yo lo estoy trabajando con Lists,pero cada vez que agregro o Elimino en la Lista,tengo que volver a pasar la lista por el Adapter en la actividad para que pueda actualizar el Recycler.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, lo tendré en cuenta

Answer (score 0):

Que tal, me gustaría compartirte una respuesta que he hecho [en este link](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/86638/c%C3%B3mo-puedo-colocar-un-recyclerview-o-un-listview-en-un-fragment-en-android-stud/86817#86817)

Aquí Explico mas o menos el funcionamiento de un Recycler. Por lo que comentas puedo imaginar que haces el cambio de tu base de datos, pero esta no se actualiza , si es así ,el problema tiene que ver con el adaptador de tu RecyclerView , para actualizarlo es tan simple como poner :

```
nombreAdaptador.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Pero en el enlace que me mandas no usas `nombreAdaptador.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: En el enlace se explica la implementación de un Recycler, en este caso en el momento en que haces el cambio de datos... (Utilzas SQL?, Firebase?) utilizas nombreAdaptador.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: mDataset  es tu lista, para poder implementarla en tu Recycler tuviste que utilizar un adaptador, el código que muestras , eliminas el dato de ls lista pero ahora el problema es que no se actualiza, para lograr esto es que utilizas   nombreAdaptador.notifyDataSetChanged();   y así avisas al adaptador de  tu Recycler que has hecho un cambio en la lista y este se actualiza.